# If range contains 0 then end sub in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, null

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("$G:$G")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "One of the cell contains 0"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

The above doesn't seem to be working across range. If I type "G1" it works.

The range of G can change based on how much data it is pulling from another sheet. When one of the cell is empty in original sheet, the new sheet has 0 in its place.

Comment: _Use CountA to count the number of cells that contain data in a range or array._ see [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.counta). What is it what you really want to do?

Comment: I want to produce message box in the event any cell in G range is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the caption of this post and the comment I guess you want to do something like that

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("$G:$G"), "=0") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "One of the cell contains 0"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: How would I add sheet name? As in Sheet1, so script only runs on that sheet.

Current I have set it to activate sheet in line above and then execute. Wondering if can be done in a single line.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$G:$G"), "=0") > 0`